# More temperature after boil the water can cook more faster the food?

Tags: thermodynamics, chemical-engineering

My Question was not well received in [physics.stackexchange.com](http://physics.stackexchange.com) and I get a simple answer when I want to know the theory inside this question. I want to cook more efficient wasting less ( gas or electricty ) so my though is this when I boil the water cooking cassava the heat is 100° costant then the flame can be reduce for not waste energy, and the water still will be 100° otherwise if I am cooking at the flame is at the maxiximum temperature this food will be cooked faster?. so we have 2 scenarios:

Minimization Energy:

Flame Low = food ready in 30 minutes

Cook Faster:

Flame High = food ready in 10 minutes

Are this escenarios related like work and energy theorem?(e.g. if i reduce the flame to medium will be ready in 20 minutes ) I want to know the performance and the waste of energy in each scenario, **which is better for save gas?.**

I take thermodynamics in my university but only law 0 and 1. and not too much of the 2nd law that is related to engineering. I know some basics of chemist process like matter&energy balance

This question is more for a professional of industrial process or chemical engineering so that's why I am posting here.

Comment: If you want to cook faster, you need a pressure cooker which allows the pot to reach higher temperatures

Comment: couple things about the english language ... temperature is thought of as elevation (because of the mercury thermometer) ... so temperature is high, higher, low, lower ..... there is no such thing as *more faster*, only *faster*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the water is 100C and atmospheric pressure the food will cook at the same speed regardless of the heat applied to the pot. Any heat in excess of what's required to keep the water 100C simply converts water into steam.

An easy way to vastly improve the efficiency of boiling food is to boil with the cover on (even if the instructions say uncovered). You can usually keep the water boiling with the stove turned down as low as 20%. You just have to be careful as the pot will boil over if the heat is too high. I've been cooking food this way for years, and it definitely does not change the cooking time.

Comment: there are some physical laws beyond gases and thermo laws related to this? I would like to learn more I like chemist process engineering ( I mean about efficiency and cost minimization )

Comment: @rubengavidia0x latent heat of vaporization means the water is at the same temperature regardless of the heat applied until all water is evaporated.  What you can do is increase the pressure, which allows the water to boil at  hotter temperature: the classic pressure cooker or the newer InstaPot.